# Decrypt an encrypted object to a char[] for memcpy

Tags: c++, decode, crypto++

I am trying to use Crypto++ to encrypt and decrypt an `unsigned char` object. To date, the encryption is fine. However, I need the final decrypted contents to be saved in a Hex format within a byte array or a char array so that I can hand it off to memcpy properly.

I am using Visual Studio 19 with the latest version of Crypto++.

```
HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(cout));
ByteQueue plain, cipher, recover;
unsigned char shellcode[] = "\xfc\xe8\x89\x00\x00\x00\x60";
unsigned char enc_shellcode[] ="\x6D\x30\xEB\x18\xF2\x01\x16";

plain.Put(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(shellcode), sizeof(shellcode));

//Encryption:
CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc;
enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

StreamTransformationFilter f1(enc, new Redirector(cipher));
plain.CopyTo(f1);
f1.MessageEnd();

cout << "Cipher text: ";
cipher.CopyTo(encoder);
encoder.MessageEnd();
cout << endl;

// Decryption
CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption dec;
dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

StreamTransformationFilter f2(dec, new Redirector(recover));
cipher.CopyTo(f2);
f2.MessageEnd();

recover.CopyAllTo(encoder);
encoder.MessageEnd();
cout << endl;

// Allocating memory with EXECUTE writes
void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof test, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

// Copying deciphered shellcode into memory as a function
memcpy(exec, /*Decrypted Shellcode..*/, sizeof test);
```

I can never get the data back to its original `unsigned char` in hex form so that I can load the data in memory... I am not very proficient in C++ and I am sure that's fairly object for some of you so this might be a simple fix or not...?

Comment: What "hex form"?`"\xfc\xe8\x89\x00\x00\x00\x60"` is just an array of numbers (`{252, 232, 137, 0, 0, 0, 96, 0}`).

Comment: There is no such thing internally as "hex form".  Those are just plain integers.  If you want to *display* hex, that is a different story.

Comment: When I say hex, I am talking about the data that is residing within the `unsigned char` variables above. I just need the final output to be in the same format as the inital input.

Comment: Then you don't need `HexEncoder` at all.

Comment: Good to know @zett42 ! How would I think cast it back into an unsigned char??

Comment: Use an `ArraySink`, for instance.

Comment: @AdamSmith -- You're still not making yourself clear.  Did you read the first comment?  Did you know that `unsigned char shellcode[] = "\xfc\xe8\x89\x00\x00\x00\x60";` is no different than `unsigned char shellcode[] = {252,232,147,0,0,0,96}`?  When you look at a byte in memory, you won't find a quote followed by slash followed by an `x` character, etc.

Comment: " I need the final decrypted contents to be saved in a Hex format " - the format something is stored in should be irrelevant. If you want something *displayed* as hex, then that's a matter of converting the stored data to your desired output form. A number is a number, whether it is stored in binary, decimal or hexadecimal form. It's still the same number. Only the display format differs.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You forgot octal -:)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and base 12 and base whatever.. there are infinitely many bases one could use to represent a number. Do you expect me to list them all?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, I do know that. I think that point I am trying to get passed is how do I get the output from the decryption routine into an acceptable format that memcpy will be able to use and execute. (i.e., How do I save the decrypted output to a variable that memcpy will accept).

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- I mentioned octal due to it being a format that can be represented in C++ source directly.

Comment: @AdamSmith Memcpy only requires you have a pointer to a buffer.  What is `test`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it was a byte object that I was trying to read the contents of the decryption routine into so that I could point memcpy to the byte object.

Answer (score 0):

> I can never get the data back to its original unsigned char in hex form so that I can load the data in memory...

`ByteQueue` and `MessageQueue` are higher level Crypto++ pipeline objects. When [data is flowing from a source to a sink](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) they are a fine choice. But they can be a bit awkward to use when you don't use a sink, like with your `memcpy`.

Below are two examples of doing what you want to do.

Also note this is not quite correct. The ciphertext size must be a multiple of the blocksize due to CBC mode and PKCS padding. In your case, the encrypted shellcode should be 16 bytes.

```
const byte enc_shellcode[] ="\x6D\x30\xEB\x18\xF2\x01\x16";
```

#### Pipeline

@zett42 had the right idea - use an `ArraySink`, and the Crypto++ pipelines will do the `memcpy` for you. In fact you don't even need `plain` or `recover`. So it would look something like below. (I am working on Linux, so I need to fake `VirtualAlloc`).

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "hex.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));
    ByteQueue cipher;

    const byte shellcode[] = "\xfc\xe8\x89\x00\x00\x00\x60";       

    const byte key[16] = {1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4};
    const byte  iv[16] = {8,7,6,5, 8,7,6,5, 8,7,6,5, 8,7,6,5};

    //Encryption
    CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc;
    enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

    ArraySource plain(shellcode, 7, true);
    StreamTransformationFilter f1(enc, new Redirector(cipher));
    plain.CopyTo(f1);
    f1.MessageEnd();

    std::cout << "Cipher text: ";
    cipher.CopyTo(encoder);
    encoder.MessageEnd();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Allocating memory with EXECUTE writes
    // void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof test, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    // Proxy for VirtualAlloc
    byte x[7];
    void* exec = reinterpret_cast<void*>(x);

    // Decryption
    CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption dec;
    dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

    ArraySink recover(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(exec), 7);
    StreamTransformationFilter f2(dec, new Redirector(recover));
    cipher.CopyTo(f2);
    f2.MessageEnd();

    // Can't use recover.CopyTo() here. ArraySink is not a source;
    // and the internal pointer is at the end of the array, not
    // the beginning of the array.
    std::cout << "Recover text: ";
    encoder.Put(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(exec), 7);
    encoder.MessageEnd();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Running the code produces the output below.

```
$ g++ test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
$ ./test.exe
Cipher text: 88BFA35C6ABF2EDF1FDCDC354721C72C
Recover text: FCE88900000060
```

#### C++ objects

You can also use C++ objects rather than the Crypto++ `ByteQueue`. This is a little easier to use.

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "hex.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));

    // The embedded NULLs mean we need to use this ctor
    const std::string shellcode("\xfc\xe8\x89\x00\x00\x00\x60", 7);
    std::string cipher;

    const byte key[16] = {1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4};
    const byte  iv[16] = {8,7,6,5, 8,7,6,5, 8,7,6,5, 8,7,6,5};

    //Encryption
    CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc;
    enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

    StreamTransformationFilter f1(enc, new StringSink(cipher));
    StringSource(shellcode, true, new Redirector(f1));

    std::cout << "Cipher text: ";
    StringSource(cipher, true, new Redirector(encoder));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Allocating memory with EXECUTE writes
    // void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof test, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    // Proxy for VirtualAlloc
    byte x[7];
    void* exec = reinterpret_cast<void*>(x);

    // Decryption
    CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption dec;
    dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

    ArraySink recover(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(exec), 7);
    StreamTransformationFilter f2(dec, new Redirector(recover));
    StringSource(cipher, true, new Redirector(f2));

    // Can't use recover.CopyTo() here. ArraySink is not a source;
    // and the internal pointer is at the end of the array, not
    // the beginning of the array.
    std::cout << "Recover text: ";
    encoder.Put(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(exec), 7);
    encoder.MessageEnd();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the same results using `std::string`:

```
$ g++ test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
$ ./test.exe
Cipher text: 88BFA35C6ABF2EDF1FDCDC354721C72C
Recover text: FCE8899B7F0000
```